# Use NSPanel for user input. Not opening up again

Tags: swift, swift2, nswindowcontroller, nspanel

I want to display a 'NSPanel' for the user to input a name for a new folder. Why a NSPanel? Because it looks awesome! It hosts one TextField and one PushButton to confirm the name. It shall also close the window when clicked.

[image]

It displays when the "add" button gets clicked in my menu. It also closes when the "done" button gets clicked in the `NSPanel`. But when I click "add" again it doesn't show up anymore. That also occurs when I close it via the normal "close button" in the title bar. So it is not explicitly related to the "done"-PushButton. I also tested implementing `func windowWillClose(notification: NSNotification)` which also doesn't get triggered in either cases. What could be the problem? Also, does it somehow need to be a "new" window every time? Or am I using this correctly for user input? I mean it just gets instantiated once and then "shown" and "unshown" or am I wrong?

So I did a new Cocoa-Class - Subclass of `NSWindowController` - and let xCode create a .xib for that also. In that .xib I "designed" the `NSPanel`. I ticked `visible at launch` without that the window wouldn't appear when the menu button gets clicked. I also hooked up an `IBOutlet` for the `NSPanel`in my Cocoa Class. My Class at the moment looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class NamingHUD: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var insertNameWindow: NSPanel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: NSTextField!
    override var windowNibName : String! {
        return "NamingHUD"
    }
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        insertNameWindow.center()
        insertNameWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
    }
    @IBAction func userSetName(sender: NSButton) {
        print("Close button clicked")
        insertNameWindow.close()
    }
}
```

In my Main Class I declared it as a variable like this:

```
var namingHUD:NamingHUD!
```

and then in `override func awakeFromNib()` as:

```
namingHUD = NamingHUD()
```

as well as in a click handler like:

```
 @IBAction func addClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        namingHUD.showWindow(nil)
    }
```

Now. When I click and `addClicked()` gets called the window shows up as expected. Fine! I enter a name and hit the "done" button and it closes the window properly. Also Fine! But when I click again, say to add another folder, the window doesn't show up anymore. I also created a Preferences Window the exact same way. But with a Window instead of a NSPanel inside. That totally works as it should.

So I clearly confused something or forget something. What could it be? I openly admit that it is the first time I am working with any kind of window outside of following a tutorial. So I clearly didn't grasp the whole concept of it. I read up about windows in Apples Developer Guide and it kinda makes sense. But... well, doesn't work at the moment. Am I "misusing" the `NSPanel`? Shouldn't be the case as it inherits from `NSWindow` or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you connect the `window` outlet of `NamingHUD` to your awesome panel? Nibs are loaded lazily:

```
namingHUD = NamingHUD()   // init the controller but doesn't load the nib
...
namingHUD.showWindow(nil) // now you are loading it for the first time
```

It works the first time because `showWindow()` loads the nib **and** show the window referenced by the `window` outlet. Your panel shows up because it's set to "Visible at launch". Your of course had no window to show.

Subsequent clicks don't load the nib file again, only order the `window` outlet to show up. That's why your panel did not show again. FYI: an `NSPanel` is a subclass of `NSWindow` so it has everything that `NSWindow` has, and then some more.

Comment: Thank you! That gave me a little bit of insight. It's working now.